# The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user

Tags: report, dashboard

Getting 'The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user.' error in partner community event the user have access to all objects and fields related to report.
Can anyone please tell me what can be a possible solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to OWD in sharing setting and enable the standard report visibility at the end.

Sharing settings in the report:

[image: Sharing settings in the report]